# How can I target an id="last_name[]_field" with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, special-characters

I am using a plugin for wordpress, and the developer created the ID using the [] characters in the name.

I can't seam to figure out how to target them with css...

```
<p id="shipping_city[]_field">stuff</p>
```

so i try

```
#shipping_city[]_field {font-size:24px;}
```

or something.. and no luck.

has anyone run into this type of thing before?

I don't want to change the developers html because this is for a form entry, and I think the [] serves a purpose...

Comment: I think you would have to escape the `[` and `]` characters as they have special meaning in CSS - https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape special characters - see [**Link**](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes)

> The following characters have a special meaning in CSS: !, ", #, $, %, &, ', (, ), *, +, ,, -, ., /, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, @, [, \, ], ^, `, {, |, }, and ~.
>
> There are two options if you want to use them. Either you use the Unicode code point — for example, the plus sign (+) is U+002B, so if you would want to use it in a CSS selector, you would escape it into \2b (note the space character at the end) or \00002b (using exactly six hexadecimal digits).
>
> The second option is far more elegant though: just escape the character using a backslash

```css
#shipping_city\[\]_field {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="shipping_city[]_field">stuff</p>
```

Comment: I'd like to add that attribute selectors also would be helpful here: `[id="shipping_city[]_field"]` — where specificity value is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape characters in css using a backslash

```
#shipping_city\[\]_field {font-size:24px;}
```

But really the developer should change the id selector if that's possible, to make the code cleaner.

Comment: Sure, I could change the id selector, but then when the plug has an update or something, I would have to change it again.

I think I would rather just use the CSS. 

git makes merging these types of things pretty easy, but still...

Comment: Good point - if it's possible you could raise it as an issue with them. They might ignore it but it's not so great to include characters in selectors that then have to be escaped in css